# get_comments() functions returns empty array on none admin roles

Tags: php, wordpress

If I am on my admin user, the function `get_comments()` returns the array of comments in the template, but for the subscriber, the array is just empty. I tried to add permission to the user but it didn't help. In any case, this should work without any permissions, for example to non logged in users (guests).

Here is my code :

```
function userCanComment ($event_date) {
    $comments = get_comments('post_id='. get_the_ID());
    echo count($comments); // returns 0 on user and 3 on admin
    foreach($comments as $comment) :
        if($comment->comment_content == (string)$event_date) 
            return "false";
    endforeach;
    return "true";
};
```

I did print everything else to check if it's working correctly, and it did work correctly! Any idea why this keeps happening?

Edit: Quests get the correct array of comments, but all users beside admin get empty array.

Comment: I am having the same problem, also with WP_Comment_Query. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to be showing everything. Is the function being called (or not being called) inside of any if block?

```
<?PHP
if($userRole == "Admin") //Or some other account role
{
   $getComments = userCanComment ($event_date);
}
else
{
  //Did you forget to call the function here?
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the answer is no, the function called in the theme single file and there is no statement for the role. As I said for none logged users its actually works.